# bootstrap not working in visual studio cordova apps how to use bootstrap files in Apache cordova apps?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

1. how to use bootstrap files in Apache cordova apps?
2. Is there any setting to do
3. in visual studio 2015 css intellisense not working

Answer (score 1):

> 1. how to use bootstrap files in Apache cordova apps?
> 2. Is there any setting to do

First, you need to download the `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.min.css` file. Then you can reference it in your `index.html` file:

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <!--reference bootstrap.min.css file here -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>BootStrapDemo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app" style="">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">BootStrap Button</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

> 3. in visual studio 2015 css intellisense not working

I guess you didn't reference it correctly. If you referenced it correctly, you will get the intelligence like this:

[image]

Comment: i followed the same procedure but still facing the same issue intellisense not working